# CSS scrollbar showing but not allowing scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to scroll content inside an div. This div is scrollable horizontally and vertically.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 8px;
  top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm facing three different problems:

1. The scrollbar doesn't work at all
2. The horizontal scrollbar doesn't show
3. The scrollbar is overlaping other elements

https://jsfiddle.net/tqLa6rg5/

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar shows, but it's at the bottom of your div, which you can't scroll to because your `body` has a `overflow: hidden;` remove that.

Comment: @HunterTurner Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Linesofcode As Hunter mentioned, remove the `overflow:hidden` from `body` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. To have percentage height to work you'll also need to set `height: 100%` to `html` tag.
2. You have `top: 20px;` on the wrapper, that makes the horizontal to be invisible, as the overall height exceeds 100%.
3. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to make the `padding` part of the box size.

See the updated example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porta tortor sed metus. Nam pretium. Sed tempor. Integer ullamcorper, odio quis porttitor sagittis, nisl erat tincidunt massa, eu eleifend eros nibh sollicitudin est. Nulla dignissim.
      Mauris sollicitudin, arcu id sagittis placerat, tellus mauris egestas felis, eget interdum mi nibh vel lorem. Aliquam egestas hendrerit massa. Suspendisse sed nunc et lacus feugiat hendrerit. Nam cursus euismod augue. Aenean vehicula nisl eu quam
      luctus adipiscing. Nunc consequat justo pretium orci. Mauris hendrerit fermentum massa. Aenean consectetuer est ut arcu. Aliquam nisl massa, blandit at, accumsan sed, porta vel, metus. Duis fringilla quam ut eros.</p>
    <p>Sed eu ligula eget eros vulputate tincidunt. Etiam sapien urna, auctor a, viverra sit amet, convallis a, enim. Nullam ut nulla. Nam laoreet massa aliquet tortor. Mauris in quam ut dui bibendum malesuada. Nulla vel erat. Pellentesque metus risus, aliquet
      eget, eleifend in, ultrices vitae, nisi. Vivamus non nulla. Praesent ac lacus. Donec augue turpis, convallis sed, lacinia et, vestibulum nec, lacus. Suspendisse feugiat semper nunc. Donec nisl elit, varius sed, sodales volutpat, commodo in, elit.
      Proin ornare hendrerit lectus. Sed non dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis suscipit. Mauris egestas tincidunt lectus. Phasellus sed quam et velit laoreet pretium. Nunc metus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is better than mine. Good catch :)

Comment: With your help I tried to adapt to my real code, and now I have a different issue. https://jsfiddle.net/hk4sfc77/1/ the body does not fit the content, to understand it better http://s33.postimg.org/mvl7mambi/Sem_T_tulo.jpg The scrollbars are now working as I want (the horizontal scroll is always visible and not in the bottom of the page). Can you help me?

Comment: @Linesofcode as I mentioned that you have `top` value set, but you can use `calc()` as needed, see https://jsfiddle.net/hk4sfc77/2/ please.

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal scroll bar shows, but it's at the bottom of your div, which you can't scroll to because your `body` has a `overflow: hidden;` remove that.

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* <--- Remove This */
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tqLa6rg5/1/)

Comment: Can you please see the answer to @Pangloss?